# NuGet Hint Path Issue with shared project for multiple solutions

Tags: .net, build, nuget-package

I Have four solutions, the first solution (lets call it common) has some common projects which I want to share. I have added what I need to the other three solutions (lets call them A,B,C) from common. One of the common projects implements the entity framework nu get package, which I added through "manage solution packages".

when I add this project to A,B or C, the solution does not compile as it can't find the entity framework DLL's reference and I have to remove the package and re-add it through "manage solution packages",it will then work. However the other solutions will not build unless I do the same to them, which will undo the mapping on the first solution. this isn't too bad but two of the three solutions will fail through an automated build with an error saying unable to resolve the package.

what I would like to achieve is some how is to be able to get solutions A,B,C to compile without having to reinstall this package every time and if possible keep it as a nu get package for the updates?

hope this makes sense.

Comment: Are you using [Automatic Package Restore](http://docs.nuget.org/consume/package-restore)?  As long as you have Visual Studio set up to automatically download packages, you should be good.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Install-Package RelativeHintPaths
```

Answer (score 0):

We work around this by modifying hint path to use $(SolutionDir) via a python script.
This could be automated if its likely to change often - also you could modify the script to search for all csproj files with glob.
This solution is preferable for us as the build server doesn't need to do any modifications and we only build via the solution files and not directly with csproj

```
import glob, os, re

def Main():
    print 'Fixing Nuget Package References'
    files = [
        r'..\Common\Common.Auth\Common.Auth.csproj',
        r'..\Common\Common.Core\Common.Core.csproj',
    ]
    for file in files: ProcessFile(file)

def ProcessFile(path):
    print 'processing ' + path
    text = ''
    with open(path) as f: text = f.read()
    updated = re.sub(r"<HintPath>(?:(?!\\packages)(?:.|\n))*\\packages", r"<HintPath>$(SolutionDir)\packages", text)
    if (text == updated): return #no update requried
    with open(path, 'w') as f: f.write(updated) 

if __name__ == "__main__":
    Main()
```